# Created a screen flow with rich text component to send email. But receiver can receives mail but the image is not visible to the receiver

Tags: visual-workflow, email-alert, screen-flow, send-email

We created a screen flow to send email without email template.
We are using rich text box for body of email.
Flow is working, but the issue is: When sending the email along with the image, the receiver receives the mail, but the image is not visible to the receiver.
So, why does the image look broken in the email and how can we solve this issue?

Below is the screenshot of email how image is lookalike.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When using a Screen Flow with a rich text box to send emails, there are a few common reasons why images might not be visible to the receiver. Here are some suggestions.

**Hosting of the Image:**

If you're embedding an image by linking to an external URL, ensure the image is hosted on a publicly accessible server. If the image is hosted on a private server or within Salesforce without public access, the receiver won't be able to view it.

**Image URL Format:**

If the image is hosted within Salesforce (e.g., in Documents or Files), ensure you're using the correct public URL format. Salesforce has specific URL formats for publicly accessible images.

**Content Security Policies:**

Some email clients have strict content security policies that block images from unknown sources or domains. Test by sending the email to different email clients to see if the behaviour is consistent.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I can't decide if I think this is AI generated or not. At any rate though, if you are using AI to generate answers, that is not allowed on this site.

Comment: As before, I ran into this problem in the past and made some notes in case this came about again. So decided to share with this user.